# Date Difference with Groovy Script Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am trying to create a Sort based on an inline Groovy Script with following code.

Basically trying to minus a date field with current time and sort it using the returned difference.

```
"sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "DateTime date = new DateTime(doc['enddate'].value); return date.minus(date , '2016-08-12T12:24:03');",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }]
```

However this method is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "DateTime.now().millis - doc.enddate.date.millis",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Val Thanks, Getting following error :  "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "failed to run inline script [DateTime.now().date.millis - doc.enddate.date.millis] using lang [groovy]"

Comment: You need to make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) and restart ES

Comment: I used desc logic as per the requirement

Comment: However I have few dates which has date value as 1800-01-01T00:00:00 I want this to be at the last, For testing purpose i just tried something like this, Could you please suggest a better approach ? `"script": "if(new DateTime(doc['enddate'].date).year == 1800){return -500000000000000; } else {DateTime.now().millis - new DateTime(doc['enddate'].date).millis}"`

Comment: Dates with year 1800 already have a negative milliseconds value (anything before Jan 1st, 1970 has), so I suggest `doc.effectiveenddate.date.millis < 0 ? -500000000000000 : (DateTime.now().millis - doc.effectiveenddate.date.millis)`