# DateDifference query in Elastic Search java API

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-java-api

I have a query in Mysql

```
select * from myTable where datediff(updated_at, created_at) >5 and created_by = 'USERX'
```

Below is myTable

```
##############################################
# ID  | created_at | updated_at | created_by #
#--------------------------------------------#
# 1   | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-09 |   USERX    #
#--------------------------------------------#
# 2   | 2018-05-02 | 2018-05-03 |   USERY    #
#--------------------------------------------#
# 3   | 2018-05-02 | 2018-05-06 |   USERX    #
##############################################
```

I tried to generate the same query in ELASTIC SEARCH JAVA API, but failed to do it. Any help will be really appreciated.

Please note I am using ES 5.7 version and Java 8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912629/date-difference-with-groovy-script-elastic-search/38912724#38912724

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try